# We keep butter in refrigerator. Can we make a passive voice starting refrigerator?

Tags: passive-voice

**We keep butter in the refrigerator.**

I know that we can have passive sentence using butter.

**Butter is kept in the refrigerator.**

can we have one using refrigerator? Isn't refrigerator an object here?

If not, why?

Comment: The object of the verb _keep_ is the butter (it's 'in _the_ refrigerator', by the way). You could say **The refrigerator is used for storing butter**.

Comment: **The butter is kept in *the* refrigerator**.

Comment: The refrigerator keeps butter. Butter keeps in the refrigerator. These are used, but they have slightly different meanings of “keep”.

Answer (score 2):

No, refrigerator is not the object of the sentence. Butter is the object. Refrigerator is part of an adverbial phrase: "in the refrigerator". "We keep butter" is a complete sentence. "In the refrigerator" gives more information about the nature of the keeping.

Here's another example:

- I cleaned the car carefully.
- I cleaned the car in the evening.

Both sentences have a subject [I], verb [cleaned], and object [the car]. "Carefully" is an adverb. It adds more detail about the verb. "In the evening" is a phrase, but functioning the same way as the adverb. Therefore it is an adverbial phrase.

So in your OP, the bolded sentences are the two correct options.

Comment: Can the phrase 'in the refrigerator' be a prepositional phrase?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't precise. It is certainly a prepositional phrase. And in this case it is an adverbial prepositional phrase, because it gives more information about the verb (where the keeping took place.)